# How to find if there is a null key in hashmap?

Tags: java, collections

Can anyone tell me how I can find whether a hashmap contains a null key or not.

Comment: map.values().stream().anyMatch( entry -> entry == null)

Comment: Not duplicate: existence test is different for dealing with an entry that might be null

Answer (score 4):

Try using `containsKey` in combination with `== null`.

Like this:

```
if (map.containsKey("your_key") && map.get("your_key") == null) {
   // your map contains a key, and it is null
}
```